# Vertically align text and image

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I know this is duplicate but sorry as solution given on other post seems not working for me or I didn't got them correctly.

I need to vertically align text and image to middle. Tried CSS property vertical-align:middle but it seems, is not working. My code is given at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zcaT3/) and as follow

```
<div class="picacollinvitecoll">
    <span>Other Collaborators:</span>
    <img width="20px" height="20px" src="https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/profile.ak/hprofile-ak-ash4/187580_670310756_917182522_q.jpg" title="Kapil Sharma" />
    <img width="20px" height="20px" src="https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/profile.ak/hprofile-ak-ash4/187580_670310756_917182522_q.jpg" title="Kapil Sharma" />
    <img width="20px" height="20px" src="https://m.ak.fbcdn.net/profile.ak/hprofile-ak-ash4/187580_670310756_917182522_q.jpg" title="Kapil Sharma" />
</div>​
```

CSS properties are

```
.picacollinvitecoll span{
    margin:0;
}
.picacollinvitecoll img{
    margin-top: 3px;
}​
```

I'm getting output as shown on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zcaT3/), which is aligned at the bottom. Can someone please update JSFiddle to make it align at 'middle'.

Comment: check this post [vertical align img], 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021676/vertical-align-img-and-text-within-li

Comment: @Kapil Sharma Do you want the image aligned relative to the text or the whole lot aligned relative to the container?

Comment: Yes I wanted them relatively aligned. Got the ans. Thanks (+1) to everyone for timely help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for CSS `vertical-align:middle`

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/zcaT3/5/)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `vertical-align: middle;` to both of the selectors (if I understand you correctly)

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/mbhLN/

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:table` for the parent div

Check the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/zcaT3/10/

Answer (score 1):

Try this code into your css:

```
.picacollinvitecoll img{
    margin-top:-3px;
    vertical-align:middle; 
    padding-top:2px;
}​
```

Answer (score -1):

here is another way to do it. use align attribute of image, here is updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/zcaT3/7/

Comment: The align property of `<img>` is not only depreciated but actually obsolete in HTML5.