# Fix custom font line-height with CSS

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I've been experiencing a strange issue when using a custom font on a new webapp i'm working on.

This custom font (FF DIN) Seem to have naturally vertical off-center line-height, which force me to put some padding-top hack to compensate the top space on element like button and input.

*Example: the font in green (Helvetica Neue) is correctly align, where the custom font we use (FF DIN) is vertically off-center:*

[image]

Is there any known way to fix that centering issue on the CSS naturally, someway to forces font baseline behavior?

Thank you.

Comment: This isn’t about line-height but about vertical placement of glyphs.

Comment: Any other plausible solution to this? apart from the accepted solution? I don't want to edit the font manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I've end up manually fixing the font myself, using help from this answer:

[UIButton custom font vertical alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535498/uibutton-custom-font-vertical-alignment)

Answer (score 23):

The issue here is not line height but vertical placement of glyphs, in particular the location of the text baseline. That’s something that the font designer has decided on; the designer draws glyphs and places them in the em square, the conceptual device that has height equal to (or defined to be) the font height. In particular, the designer decides how much space there is below the baseline on one hand and above the height of uppercase letters on the other. Typically these spaces are equal, or almost equal, but they need not be. If they are substantially different, the intended use of the font is probably special and does not include usage like the one shown in the image. This suggests that the font choice should be reconsidered, but let’s assume it’s fixed.

There are several ways to deal with the problem. If there is too much space below the letters, reducing `line-height` makes it smaller, but it also affects the space above. Top padding helps in a sense, but it increases the total height occupied by the element. You can also play with `vertical-align`, but it affects the height of line boxes.

Probably the simplest approach is to use **relative positioning**, assuming that the problem deals with a one-liner text. Relative positioning just displaces content in a specified way, without affecting the layout otherwise. You would need a wrapper for this, i.e. an element that contains the text, so that you can displace just the text, not the background.

The following demo uses a Google font, Candal, which has a similar problem, but in a different direction: the baseline is too low. Modifications of this approach to meet the original problem should be obvious, but the exact amount of displacement needs to be determined empirically (or from information extracted from the font file using a font inspector). Naturally, the `em` unit should be used here, even if you set font size in pixels or points (so that the code does not need to be changed if the font size is changed some day).

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Candal' rel='stylesheet'>
<style>
div { font-family: Candal }
div { background: lightgreen; font-size: 200%}
</style>
<p>What we have got initially:
<div>BRAKE HOSE AND AIR CHAMBER</div>
<p>Reducing line height (even “setting solid”) does not really help:
<div style="line-height: 1">BRAKE HOSE AND AIR CHAMBER</div>
<p>But displacing the text upwards by 0.1em does:
<div><span style="position: relative; bottom: 0.1em">
BRAKE HOSE AND AIR CHAMBER</span></div>
```

Comment: That's working, but I'm looking for a scalable way to change this accross all my element (button/input), I can't put span in every button, and that won't fix input align.

Comment: For buttons, the padding method probably works well enough. However, in general, if a font causes problems like this, a different font should be chosen.

Answer (score 19):

There are new [font-face descriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) properties that were recently introduced into CSS for this kind of purpose. They allow CSS to override some of the information contained in the font file itself.

Inside the `@font-face` description of your font, you can now add:

- [`ascent-override`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/ascent-override)
- [`descent-override`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/descent-override)
- [`line-gap-override`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/line-gap-override)

In the case of this random google font used in another answer, it seems that a slight tweak to `ascent-override` is what one might want.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Candal Without Override';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/candal/v15/XoHn2YH6T7-t_8c9BhQIldUhlg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Candal With Override';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/candal/v15/XoHn2YH6T7-t_8c9BhQIldUhlg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
  ascent-override: 90%;
}

p {
  background: lightgreen; 
  font-size: 200%;
}

.regular {
  font-family: 'Candal Without Override';
}

.override {
  font-family: 'Candal With Override';
}
```

```html
<div>with <code>ascent-override</code></div>
<p class="override">BRAKE HOSE AND AIR CHAMBER</p>
<div>without <code>ascent-override</code></div>
<p class="regular">BRAKE HOSE AND AIR CHAMBER</p>
```

Comment: For anyone wanting to try this. Yes it works but of course the new IE that is Safari doesnt support this at the time of writing.

Comment: Thank you for saving my sanity  When I fixed the 1px offset in one place, it was misaligned in another, and vice versa. Couldn't find a unified fix, but of course we're using a custom font (with an incorrect vertical position).

Answer (score 3):

This is something I've come across recently. The baseline on the fonts I was using for some reason did not line up, so I aligned to the bottom and increased the line height instead of adding padding.

This is how I solved my issue, if you have a link to a code pen I can check if it will work for you, or if another solution would be better.

```
p {

    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    line-height: 1.5;

}
```

Comment: I've tried but that didn't change anything, I can't really put a codepen up as this font is protected

Answer (score 3):

I have had that problem aswell in past, even different browsers gave different line heights! I think it happens when using the webfont generator and can only be fixed with using different line-height as far as I know.

Did you try fontsquirrel? There are some options with different results.

http://everythingfonts.com/font-face

http://www.font2web.com/

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

https://www.web-font-generator.com/

Comment: Fontsquirrel has a option to modify x-height, except font from fontshop are protected ..

Comment: "Fix vertical metrics" on https://transfonter.org/ did the job for me.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome I've found that if you are using a font-face declaration. You can solve the line-height issue with either a style="" call i the HTML, or simply declaring the line-height AFTER the font declaration in your CSS.

I think Chrome just doesn't know how to calculate the line-height until it's rendered the custom font.