# CSS Windows compatibility

Tags: html, css, windows, cross-browser

The logo of this page is shown out of its place in windows:

[contraindicaciones.net](http://contraindicaciones.net)

But the markup is very simple. **What of this is incompatible with Windows?**

Here is a Windows7 + Chrome49 test screencapture (is the same in newer Windows OS):

[image: test screen capture]

HTML:

```
<div class="site-branding hidden-xs">
  <div class="s s-weblog"></div>
  <a class="site-title" href="<?= esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
  <p class="site-description">
    <?php bloginfo('description'); ?>
  </p>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.site-branding {
  text-align: center;
  .s-weblog {
    font-size: 128px;
    height: 135px;
  }
  .site-title {
    font-size: 28px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .site-description {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-style: italic;
  }
}
```

Thak you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

the issue seems to be with the font itself. have a read here [Fix custom font line-height with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101813/fix-custom-font-line-height-with-css)

a simple fix would be to use relative/absolute positioning

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried this workaround with absolute positioning. It implies that other elements should have absolute position. After do it, the logo still outside its place in Windows!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is something with

```
font-family:contraindi;
```

I tried to change `content:"some text"` and remove `font-family` and I've got something like this [image]

Comment: Yes, I have generated this font from SVG, with gulp https://github.com/nfroidure/gulp-iconfont. Most likely I did something wrong. The documentation of these tools is very poor.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
.s:before {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: contraindi;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  top: -134px;
  left: 71px;
}
```

Comment: I did it, without results. I tried also some other setup for before pseudoclase. Most likely I did something wrong when I build the font from SVG.