# Fix vertical positioning and line-height in webfont

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

My client is using a custom font for his website, the issue is that the postionning of characters inside the line-height is broken.
So everything is not center except if I add custom padding everywhere (see screenshots below) ...

Text line-height : 1 :

[image: Text line-height : 1]

Button without custom padding :

[image: Button without custom padding]

I tried to fix it using advanced settings in font-squirrel but I don't seem to find the right ones. Any tips ?

Comment: Might offer help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101813/fix-custom-font-line-height-with-css

Comment: I ended up finding the real webfont instead of converting it but that fix could work too.