# Webfont with bad space and how to fix it

Tags: css, web, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I'd never faced this kind of deal, so I'm figuring out how to do it.
I bought a font called [Core Sans C](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/s-core/core-sans-c/) and it comes with a problem (I see it as a problem). At the bottom there's an extra space that it comes with the font (not added through CSS).

[Example of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjNoo.png)

As you can see on the image, the button has more space on the bottom than on the top. I tried fixing it with CSS without success and I don't want to add more space on top to compensate the extra one below.

The HTML and CSS used on the image is the one below:

```css
.example {
  display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-family: "Core Sans C";
    background: black;
    border: 1px solid;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 95px;
    }
```

```html
<button class="example">Hello</button>
```

(Of course I can't add the font because it is a payed one, but you can try going to the Core Sans C link I provided and then with inspect element create a button and see it by yourself)

Does anybody faced the same and has any idea on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably can fix it using the `line-height` and/or `vertical-align` properties. But if a font is set to high, you should abandon that font a pick a better crafted one. You will have pain with such fonts over and over again. See also: [Fix custom font line-height with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101813/fix-custom-font-line-height-with-css) and [Deep dive CSS: font metrics, line-height and vertical-align](https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align)

Comment: That space is there **for a reason**...it not only spaces out the text from the line above/below but **more importantly** is there for *descenders* & ascenders. I'd suggest you review how typography actually works. Try typing lower case `g` or `q`, then you'll see what that space is for,